# Perl Distributed parallel computing

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, perl-module

I would like to know if there are any perl modules available to enable distributed parallel computation similar to apache hadoop.

Example,
A perl script to be executed in many machines parallely when submitted to a client node.

Comment: How about Grid::Machine http://search.cpan.org/~casiano/GRID-Machine/. I'm not familiar with this area myself, but it looks like a possibility.

Comment: along the same lines ... since you do mention hadoop, perhaps you are interested in MapReduce:  http://search.cpan.org/~drrho/Parallel-MapReduce-0.09/lib/Parallel/MapReduce.pm

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of the Many-core Engine for Perl.

During the next several weekends, I will take [MCE](https://metacpan.org/release/MCE) for a spin with [Gearman::XS](https://metacpan.org/release/Gearman-XS). MCE is good at maximizing available cores on a given node. Gearman is good at job distribution and includes a lot of features such as load balancing. Combining the two together was my thought for scaling MCE horizontally across many nodes. :) I did not share this news with anybody until just now.

Why are the two modules a good fit (my humble opinion):

1. For distribution, one needs some sort of chunking engine. MCE is a chunking engine -- so breaking up input is natural to MCE. Essentially MCE can be used at both sides, the job submission host as well as on the worker node for maximizing available cores.
2. For worker nodes, MCE follows a bank-queuing model when processing input data. This helps guarantee that all CPUs remain busy from the start of the job till the very end. As workers being to idle down, the remaining "working" are processing their very last chunk.

One's imagination is the limit here -- there are so many possibilities with these 2 modules working together. When writing MCE, I first focused on the node side. Job distribution is next obviously and I did a search and came across Gearman::XS. The 2 modules can chunk happily together :) Job distribution side (bigger chunks), once on node (smaller chunks). All the networking stuff is handled by Gearman.

Basically, there's no need for me to write the job distribution aspect when Gearman::XS is already quite nice. This has been my plan. I will write about Gearman::XS + MCE soon.

BTW: Folks can do similar things with GRID-Machine + MCE I imagine. MCE's beauty is on maximizing all available cores on any given node.

Another magical thing about MCE is that one may not want 200 nodes * 16 workers all reading/writing from/to the NFS server for example. That will impact the NFS server greatly. BTW: RHEL 6.4 will include pNFS (parallel NFS).  With MCE, workers can call the "do" method to serialize writes/reads from NFS. So instead of 200 * 16 = 3200 attacking NFS, it becomes just 200 maximum requests against the NFS server at any given time (1 per physical node).

When writing MCE, grace can be applied for many scenarios. I need to add more wikis to MCE's home page [MCE at code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/many-core-engine-perl/). In addition, MCE eats really big log files for breakfast :) Check out egrep.pl and wc.pl under the [examples](https://metacpan.org/source/MARIOROY/MCE-1.404/examples) dir. It even beats the wide finder project with sequential IO (powerful slurp IO among many workers).

Check out the [images](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARIOROY/MCE-1.404/images/) included with the MCE distribution. Oh, do not forget to check out the main [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) site as well.

What's left after this? Humm, the web piece. One idea which comes to mind is to use [Mojo](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.87/). There are many options. This is just one:

Gearman::XS + MCE + Mojolicious

Again, one can use GRID-Machine instead of Gearman::XS if wanting to communicate through SSH.

Anyway, that was my plan to use an already available job distribution module. For MCE, my focus was on maximizing performance on a single node -- to include chunking, serializing, bank-queuing model, user tasks (allows for many roles), number sequencing among workers, and sequential slurp IO.

-- mario

Answer (score 1):

You might look into something as simple as a message queue like [ZeroMQ](https://metacpan.org/module/ZMQ). I'm sure a [CPAN search](https://metacpan.org) could help with some other suggestions.

Recently there has been some talk of the Many Core Engine [MCE](https://metacpan.org/module/MCE) module, which you might want to investigate, I don't know for sure that it lets you parallelize off the host computer, but it seems like it wouldn't be a big step given its stated purpose.

Comment: This is a good suggestion for thinking in terms of piecing together a system.  ZeroMQ works as glue connect components in various network topologies and has the benefit of being able to connect machines running code written in a variety of languages.  Think of it as an efficient, programming-friendly message protocol with library support in a number of languages.

Answer (score 0):

The `GRID` module on CPAN is designed for working with distributed computing.

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/GRID-Machine/lib/GRID/Machine/perlparintro.pod

Answer (score 0):

[Argon](http://argon.artfulcode.net) may provide what you are looking for (disclaimer - I'm the author). It allows you to set up an arbitrary network of workers, each of which runs a process pool (using [Coro::ProcessPool](http://search.cpan.org/~jeffober/Coro-ProcessPool/lib/Coro/ProcessPool.pm)).

Creating a task is pretty simple:

```
use Argon::Client;

my $client = Argon::Client->new(host => "somehost", port => 8000);
my $result = $client->queue(sub {
    use My::Work::Module qw(do_work);
    my $task_id = shift;
    do_work($task_id);
});
```